# Setting style properties in a web user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

With ASP.Net it is possible to set the style of a property by doing this:

```
textbox.Style.Add("background-color", "yellow")
```

I have a web user control where I would like to be able to set style attibutes on the textbox element in a generic fashion like this. Obviously it's easy to provide a setter for the background color, but I'd like users to be able to set any style attribute without my having to provide specific setters for each one.

Thanks

John

Comment: Use css instead that's more easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide two methods:

```
public void SetTextBoxStyle(string attribute, string value)
{
    textbox.Attributes[attribute] = value;
}

public string GetTextBoxStyle(string attribute)
{
    return textbox.Attributes[attribute];
}
```

Then you can set it in this way:

```
myUC.SetTextBoxStyle("background-color", "yellow");
string color = ctrl.GetTextBoxStyle("background-color"); // yellow
string noError = ctrl.GetTextBoxStyle("FOO");            // null
ctrl.SetTextBoxStyle("background-color", "red");         // no errror, now red
```

Comment: That's certainly better than anything I've thought of, thanks.